# ajax script for chat user bug on ie

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, chat

I have the following AJAX script (include chat.php and `onload=online()` at `<body>` index.php) which shows the user who's online and works well in Firefox and Chrome, but when I try to log in with IE8 the script doesn't work.

Can anyone can help me solve this? Maybe the AJAX script is wrong or not compatible with IE?

```
function online(){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            document.getElementById("online").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","proses-chat.php");
    xmlhttp.send();
    setTimeout("online()", 8000);
}

function autofocus(){
    document.form_login.elements['username'].focus();
}
```

Comment: What is the error, hit f12 and look in script/console. Also highly recommended to use jQuery for all Ajax

Comment: I agree with mplungjan. Doing your AJAX this way is highly discouraged. Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: maybe this helps: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_7/xmlhttponreadystatechange-not-working-in-internet/e5aebea9-b1b3-48da-87f6-8c44e2731270?msgId=85c6493a-8781-4722-b176-efc89a9ea7d8

apparently if you receive some non-ascii characters, it breaks in ie, so you might wanna try POST instead of GET.

Comment: @mplungjan : no error found XD.. To Alex i already try with post method and didnt working too, the user online didnt show XD.. Im newbie with this ajax im stressed up anyone help me T_T

Answer (score 0):

solved in 1 days :D, the problem isn't with ajax script, but with setcookies()

```
setcookie('username',$username,time()+36000,'http://$domain');
setcookie('password',$password,time()+36000,'http://$domain');
//$domain as define as $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = localhost
```

that's my cookies at check_login.php before, at last IE and Safari didnt read the localhost and i'm replace with :

```
setcookie('username',$username,time()+3600,'/');
setcookie('password',$password,time()+3600,'/');
```

that means cookies accept for all session and address and its work on IE and Safari too :D, dont forget to destroy the cookies

```
setcookie('username', '',time()-3600, '/');
setcookie('password', '',time()-3600, '/');
```

thx for all reply and suggest before, maybe the solution can help someone who has problem like me thx